# Receiver calling service of another application

Tags: android, android-service

I want to call a service from broadcast receiver of another application. I have tried to use the intent(explicit) in receiver class as follows.

```
ComponentName name = new ComponentName("com.example.mnit.servicetosd", "com.example.mnit.servicetosd.ServicetoSd");

Intent a = new Intent();
a.setComponent(name);
a.putExtra("destination", (Serializable) sb);
context.startService(a);
```

But unluckily the service is not called. Can someone help with some code snippet or tell me if I m doing something wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using application service in another application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336595/using-application-service-in-another-application)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the attribute *exported="true"* for the ServicetoSd service component.

Comment: yes, already added, no help .service android:name="com.example.mnit.servicetosd.ServicetoSd" android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true" android:process=":service"